# ONVIF PTZ GetStatus decimals accuracy

Tags: python-onvif

I'm using ONVIF PTZ using python. in order to get the status of the camera i call the following function :

```
def get_status(self):
        """
        prints current camera position.
        """
        status = self.ptz.GetStatus(self.status_req)
        self.full_status = status
        return (
            status['Position']['PanTilt']['x'],
            status['Position']['PanTilt']['y'],
            status['Position']['Zoom']['x']
            )
```

i get the position in motor values (-1 to 1) with 2 decimal points (e.g 0.85). however, i need more accurate values. I know that this is not a problem of the motor itself but only rounding process inside GetStatus(), because i can give the command with more decimal numbers and get an accurate movement.
is there a way to get more decimals from GetStatus?

tried to get values from GetStatus with more accuracy using onvif-python api